# How to set video resolution in Android video recorder?

Tags: android, video, resolution, video-recording

I am following [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/videobasics.html) of Android developers to record a video. I am able to record but in some default video resolution. How can I go about setting to specific video resolution for recording the video?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need a customized video encoder instead of native video encoder (the outcome of which can only be a pre-defined resolution and can not be customized). Suggest you get ffmpeg in Android build, can do the encoding with ffmpeg, which can resize the video to any resolution you want. Also ffmpeg comes in with great arm/neon optimization, so performance-wise should be OK.